# Sql query to get total orders (count) by customer type

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables "Orders" and "Customers".

I want to count number of orders according to customer type in each month, week and in each.

Order table has orderid and CustomerIDfields.

Customers table has CustomerID and CustomerTypeID field.

I have tried below query :-

```
SELECT 
                "Month" = month(o.OrderDate)
                 , "Year" = year(o.OrderDate)
                 , NoOfCustomer = Count(o.Total)                     
            FROM
                Orders o        
              INNER JOIN 
              Customers C on C.CustomerID = o.CustomerID                          
            WHERE
                o.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                AND o.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
            GROUP BY
                month(o.OrderDate)
              , year(o.OrderDate)

            ORDER BY
                year(o.OrderDate)
              , month(o.OrderDate)
```

I want result something like below :-

```
Month   Year  NoOfCustomer CustomerType
1       2013    45625         1
2       2013    12131         2
3       2013    54544         3
4       2013    7888          4
1       2013    5652          1
2       2013    5655          2
3       2013    5522          3
4       2013    555           4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What result are you getting with that query

Comment: from what i see you should add the customer type to group by clause too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, Thanks all for your help and time :-

```
SELECT  2013 as [Year],
        months.number,
        Amount = SUM(COALESCE(o.Total,0)),
        C.CustomerTypeID
FROM    Customers C
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='p' and number between 1 and 12) months
LEFT JOIN [Orders] o on C.CustomerId = o.CustomerId and YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2013 and MONTH(o.OrderDate) = months.number
GROUP BY months.number, C.CustomerTypeID 
ORDER BY months.number, C.CustomerTypeID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT MONTH(o.OrderDate) as MonthValue, 
       YEAR(o.OrderDate) as YearValue, 
       C.CustomerType, Count(o.Total) as NoOfOrders
FROM Orders o        
INNER JOIN Customers C on C.CustomerID = o.CustomerID                          
WHERE o.OrderDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 00:00:00 AM')
AND o.OrderDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 23:59:59 PM')
GROUP BY MONTH(o.OrderDate), 
         YEAR(o.OrderDate), 
         C.CustomerType 
ORDER BY MONTH(o.OrderDate),
         YEAR(o.OrderDate)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to get result for each month for every customer type then you need to add UNION like below :

```
; with CTE AS
(
       SELECT MONTH(CAST('01/01/2013' AS DateTime)) [Month], 2013 [Year], CustomerType, 0 NoOfCustomers 
       FROM Customers
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT [MONTH] + 1, 2013 [Year], CustomerType, 0 NoOfCustomers  
       FROM CTE 
       WHERE [Month] <= 12 
       AND CustomerType NOT IN 
       (
           SELECT C.CustomerType 
           FROM [Orders] O INNER JOIN Customers C ON C.CustomerID = o.CustomerID    
           WHERE MONTH(O.OrderDate) = CTE.[Month] AND YEAR(O.OrderDate) = 2013
       )
  )

SELECT * FROM
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT  [Month], [Year], CustomerType, NoOfCustomers  FROM CTE
    UNION
    SELECT MONTH(o.OrderDate) as [Month], 
           2013 as [Year], 
           C.CustomerType, 
           COUNT(o.Total) as NoOfCustomers
    FROM [Orders] o        
    INNER JOIN Customers C on C.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    WHERE YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2013
    GROUP BY MONTH(o.OrderDate), C.CustomerType 
    ) tt
 ORDER BY [Month], [Year], CustomerType
```

Comment: Thanks @Upendra, but it is giving error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'."

Comment: Sorry, one comma was there, I have updated answer, try now. Also I have changed datetime to compare as you missed records after 12 noon for 31st Dec and before 12 noon for 1st Jan.

Comment: thanks @Upendra, It is working fine, just one more requirement. please see http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/a4f44f1c-2f0a-4ace-9005-a1af205d298c/e14d43ed26f9886378cbdacf5789ec99 , customertype 4 does not have any value for month 4, can we show 0 as a default for it ?

Comment: Ok, just change INNER JOIN to RIGHT JOIN and try again

Comment: it added some extra nulls, please see http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/ba828c15-83ca-4189-808b-3181f36b6d11/0ff70d89c0504c410127f2e0d136c464

Comment: Thanks @ Upendra, previous query is giving correct result, problem is that, customertype 4 does not have any entry for month 4, so it is not showing in result. But I just want 0 as default in noofcustomer column for customer type 4.

Comment: If you want to add 0 result for month 4 only then try my updated query

Comment: Sorry @Upendra, its not for only month 4, there can be other months that have no values for other customertype too.

Comment: That's why I written UNION for all months. Now tell me you want result for all months for all CustomerType or only for CustomerType which have orders ?

Comment: it must show results(noofcustomer) for Customer 1,2,3,4 and 5, and if there is no count then 0.

Comment: Then you need to union for all months, check my updated answer

Comment: ok, but Order table does not have column "CustomerType", it only has "CustomerId" column and "Customers" table has "CustomerId" column.

Comment: Hi, please have a reference of attached scrren shot http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/1354ec40-3080-4c2e-ab8a-5f9afa6b85c5/69abaa7d6e3e193fc9850a7a683e9a2e , it is giving similar type of result for different table.

Comment: thanks @Upendra, there is only 1 issue, "orders" table does not have "customertype" column, it only has "customerid" column, that is references with Customers tables "customerid" column.

Comment: Yes, I have updated query to get customerType from customers table. Please run my updated query

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Upendra, but there is still "o.CustomerType" (o is for Orders table) in query, but order table does not have CustomerType.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
    DECLARE @DateStart DATETIME, @DateEnd DATETIME;
    SET @DateStart = CONVERT(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM');
    SET @DateEnd = CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM');

    SELECT 
    MONTH(o.OrderDate) [Month]
    , YEAR(o.OrderDate) [Year]
    , ISNULL(C.CustomerType,0) [CustomerType]
    , COUNT(o.Total) [NoOfCustomer]                  
    FROM Orders o        
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers C on C.CustomerID = o.CustomerID                          
    WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN  @DateStart AND @DateEnd
    GROUP BY MONTH(o.OrderDate), YEAR(o.OrderDate), ISNULL(C.CustomerType,0)
    ORDER BY [Year],[Month],[CustomerType];
```

UPDATE

```
    DECLARE @DateStart DATETIME, @DateEnd DATETIME;
    DECLARE @CustTypeTable TABLE(CustomerType INT);
    DECLARE @i INT = 0;
    /*Create table variable for customer types*/
    WHILE @i < 5
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @CustTypeTable
        SELECT @i
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    /*The statement will force all CustomerTypes with a "fake" table*/
    DECLARE @StagingTable TABLE([Month] INT, [Year] INT, CustomerType INT)
    INSERT INTO @StagingTable
    SELECT 
    MONTH(o.OrderDate) [Month]
    , YEAR(o.OrderDate) [Year]
    , T.CustomerType
    FROM Orders o  
    CROSS JOIN @CustTypeTable T
    GROUP BY MONTH(o.OrderDate), YEAR(o.OrderDate), T.CustomerType


    SET @DateStart = CONVERT(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM');
    SET @DateEnd = CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM');

    /*Create another staging table for results*/
    DECLARE @StagingTable2 TABLE([Month] INT, [Year] INT, CustomerType INT, [NoOfCustomer] BIGINT)
    INSERT INTO @StagingTable2
    SELECT 
    MONTH(o.OrderDate) [Month]
    , YEAR(o.OrderDate) [Year]
    , C.CustomerType [CustomerType]
    , COUNT(o.Total) [NoOfCustomer]                  
    FROM Orders o        
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers C on C.CustomerID = o.CustomerID                          
    WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN  @DateStart AND @DateEnd
    GROUP BY MONTH(o.OrderDate), YEAR(o.OrderDate), C.CustomerType
    ORDER BY [Year],[Month],[CustomerType];

    /*Now lets join them up*/
    SELECT 
     T1.Year
    , T1.Month
    , T1.CustomerType
    , T2.[NoOfCustomer]
    FROM @StagingTable T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @StagingTable2 T2 ON T2.Year = T1.Year AND T2.Month = T1.Month AND T2.CustomerType =  T1.CustomerType
```

Thats about as much as I can do for you

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, it is very close. http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/81461f09-38b2-42d4-bdec-c3017d4a1672/944ff1f6e7f6915344ff0fdebae2b2d4 , customertype 4 does not have any value for month 4, can we show 0 as a default for it ?

Comment: changed JOIN and added ISNULL

Comment: Sorry, it has added some extra "o", and for month 4 customer type 4 still not coming as 0, please see http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/7852391f-5d5a-45cd-8924-b8095db6c72b/835784536c913ca24013177e094755f8

Comment: There is no customer type 4 for that entry, that is why it does not return any value, we are just swapping NULL for 0.

Comment: Yes @Adrian, month 4 does not have any entry for customer type 4, so i want "0" as default for it in "NoOfCustomer" column.

Comment: so it must show results for Customer 1,2,3,4 and 5 only? and if there is no count then 0?

Comment: Yes @Adrian, exactly this I want.

Comment: sorry not giving desire result, please see http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/e4901359-c070-4171-831d-baca7165908c/967cb0f9441c84f69db1e968571770f5

Comment: Hi, please have a reference of attached scrren shot http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/1354ec40-3080-4c2e-ab8a-5f9afa6b85c5/69abaa7d6e3e193fc9850a7a683e9a2e , it is giving similar type of result for different table.